# How to properly manage messages sent to a thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my Android app, I use C++ to do some work. In my C++ code, I use a thread to do some tasks. Using [this example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169105/Cplusplus-std-thread-Event-Loop-with-Message-Queue) and [this example](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/2/1/c11-implementing-a-dispatch-queue-using-stdfunction), here is how I proceed (I simplified the actual code to keep it easy to read):

```
std::thread* threadLocal;
std::queue<ThreadMessage*> queueLocale;
std::mutex mutexLocal;
std::condition_variable cvLocal;

struct ThreadMessage
{
    ThreadMessage(int i)
    {
        id = i;
    }
    int id;
};

void MyWorkerThread::createThread()
{
    if (!threadLocal)
    {
        threadLocal = new std::thread(&MyWorkerThread::process, this);
    }
}

void MyWorkerThread::sendTask1()
{
    if (threadLocal)
    {
        // message:
        ThreadMessage* threadMessage = new ThreadMessage(MSG_TASK_1);

        // send the message:
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutexLocal);
        queueLocale.push(std::move(threadMessage));
        cvLocal.notify_one();
    }
}

void MyWorkerThread::sendTask2()
{
    if (threadLocal)
    {
        // message:
        ThreadMessage* threadMessage = new ThreadMessage(MSG_TASK_2);

        // send the message:
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutexLocal);
        queueLocale.push(std::move(threadMessage));
        cvLocal.notify_one();
    }
}

void MyWorkerThread::process()
{
    while (1)
    {
        // init :
        ThreadMessage* threadMessage = 0;

        // waiting for messages :
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutexLocal);
            while (queueLocale.empty())
            {
                cvLocal.wait(lock);
            }
            threadMessage = std::move(queueLocale.front());
            queueLocale.pop();
        }

        // tasks :
        switch (threadMessage->id)
        {
            case MSG_TASK_1:
            {
                doSomeWork1();
                delete threadMessage;
                break;
            }

            case MSG_TASK_2:
            {
                doSomeWork2();
                delete threadMessage;
                break;
            }

            default:
            {
                delete threadMessage;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works well in most cases, but sometimes, my app crashes when a `delete threadMessage` is called, and I don't understand why (since I don't see how it can be called twice on a same object).

Here are the reasons why I need to send messages to a thread, instead of just creating new threads each time I want to run `doSomeWork1()` or `doSomeWork2()`:

- The `doSomeWork1()` and `doSomeWork2()` functions have to be executed in the same thread
- One of those functions is very frequently called (approx. 200 times / sec), so I don't want to create a thread each time

So my question is: what is the proper way to send a message to a thread, and manage it inside the thread, to avoid error on the `delete`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see a smoking gun, but some observations: (1) the message pointer should _always_ be held in a `std::unique_ptr`, never a bare pointer, for exception safety; (2) the extra if-empty check after the condition variable loop in `process()` is pointless; (3) if the message `id` is not one of the two case values, the message pointer is not `delete`d at all (addressing (1) would also address this).

Comment: @TypeIA Thanks for your answer (I fixed (2) and (3) by the way). But here we are, I don't see any problem either but I still have a bug on delete threadMessage. Apparently, there are safer ways to manage the threadMessage object, but I still don't know how to make it work... Also, how can I implement (1) in the above example?

Comment: The issue may lie outside the code you posted. You should try to create a [mcve]. As for (1), read about [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and use it - you'll need to use [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) to transfer the `unique_ptr` into and out of the queue. This doesn't seem to be the problem though, just an improvement and good practice in general.

Comment: I finally managed to implement (1). And apparently, it came from outside this code example, since I made some changes and everything works so far. Thanks for your help.